# PouchDB not detecting sqlite plugin using cordova (iOS)

Tags: xcode, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm building a mobile app using Ionic. I've installed pouchDB (latest version 5.2.1) and have it saving data. I've also installed the SQLlite cordova plugin (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage). As per their [docs](http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html) (see section titled SQLite plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap) if the SQLlite plugin is present PouchDB should automagically use this (also mentioned in various blogs). To test pouch is using the SQLlite plugin they recommend you running `db.info().then(console.log.bind(console));`.

When I do this I get:

```
{"doc_count":2,"update_seq":104,"sqlite_plugin":false,"websql_encoding":"UTF-8","db_name":"test","auto_compaction":true,"adapter":"websql"}
```

This is the problem. My app doesn't seem to be using SQLlite to store the data from what I can tell.

I've build the app and deployed using xcode to my device. Using Safari remote debugger I've inspected the app and verified `window.sqlitePlugin` is available in the console, which gives me:

`{sqliteFeatures: {isSQLitePlugin: true}, echoTest: function, openDatabase: function, deleteDatabase: function} = $1`.

Why is my app not using the plugin to store the data?

Are there any more checks I can do? I don't seem to be able to see any DB specific files in xcode, I have however noticed that in Xcode under build targets -> frameworks that `libz.dylib`, `libsqlite3.dylib` and `libiconv.dylib` are red and therefore missing.

[image: Xcode build target frameworks]

Could this be the issue? I've crawled SO and tried adding the .tbd files but that doesn't seem to do anything...

Version number which may be helpful:

- Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
- Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
- Gulp local:  Local version 3.9.0
- Ionic Version: 1.1.1
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.5
- ios-sim version: 5.0.6
- Node Version: v5.0.0
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build
  version 7C1002

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your SQLite plug `<script>` tags are loaded before your PouchDB `<script>` tags.  Since they are added dynamically with ionic, I had to put the pouchDB `<script>` tags right before the `</body>` tag.

I figured this out after reading [@nlawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680742/nlawson)'s answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35047711/266426):

> There is a demo of [a Cordova app using PouchDB and the SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-cordova-hello-world-with-sqlite-plugin). Mostly likely you just need to make sure that SQLite Plugin `<script>` is loaded before the PouchDB `<script>`.