# Issues with PouchDB + SQLite on ionic 2

Tags: sqlite, pouchdb

I followed all the steps for PouchDB setup and SQLite. I am facing following issues:

1) this._db.info().then(console.log.bind(console)) - shows Adapter: websql , sqlite_plugin: false

```
Object
    adapter:"websql"
    auto_compaction:false
    db_name:"bakbak"
    doc_count:15
    sqlite_plugin:false
    update_seq:15
    websql_encoding:"UTF-8"
```

I am not sure what i did wrong.

2) App is working fine on Chrome. On firefox it threw an error: this.db.sync is not a function. I changed it to PouchDB.sync then error is gone. Why it happened?

3) On firefox and IE After making above change i am getting "EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Adapter is missing".

is this bug resolved: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pouchdb/sqlite/pouchdb/-ROWHfB3Ty0/6qEfRkf6MTkJ

I tried to follow the advice here: [Ionic PouchDb Sqlite plugin issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046932/ionic-pouchdb-sqlite-plugin-issue)

But i do not have any pouchdb library imported in my index.html. It is not there in js folder. I can find it in node-modules folder.

```
<body>
<ion-app></ion-app>
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support   -->
<script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
<script src="build/js/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
<script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I made the following change to enable sqlite2 plugin:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db;

    alert("window.cordova: " + window.cordova);
    alert("window.SQLitePlugin: " + window.SQLitePlugin);

    if (window.cordova && window.SQLitePlugin) { // because Cordova is platform specific and doesn't work when you run ionic serve               
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ "name": "bakbak" }); //device - SQLite
        alert("device db (SQLite) loaded");
    } else {

        db = window.openDatabase("APSNetMobileDb", "1.0", "bakbak", 100 * 1024 * 1024); // browser webSql, a fall-back for debugging
        alert("browser db (WebSQL) loaded");
    }
    </script>
```

Alerts show that cordova and sqlite are undefined

Answer (score 0):

"Adapter is missing" is a PouchDB error indicating that it can't find the `adapter` that was passed in to the `PouchDB` constructor. Did you misspell it? It should be: `var db = new PouchDB('dbname', {adapter: 'websql'})`.

OTOH it might not be that, because I see in your output `sqlite_plugin:false` meaning that the SQLite Plugin was not correctly loaded.

You may want to try [SQLite Plugin 2](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2) since it is the best-supported SQLite Plugin in terms of PouchDB support. Else make sure that `window.sqlitePlugin` is defined, because that shows that the plugin was loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi Nolan - I already added SQLite plugin 2 and it is still showing the same error. I tried to define: window.sqlitePlugin but i could not do it. I found this piece of code: var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase( {name: "demo.db"}); I got this error: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined. I must be doing something wrong. Please help.

Comment: I setup the window.sqlitePlugin but still the same error. In the setup of window.sqliteplugin it shows that plugin is not loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure why the plugin isn't loaded. You might want to read [this tutorial](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/) or try [a sample Cordova app using SQLite Storage](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-cordova-hello-world-with-sqlite-plugin).